# How to draw ASCII art on python

Tags: python, ascii-art

I'm having a problem printing out a specific ASCII art that I saw and was wondering if anyone could help me. The program does not want to run, but I don't know where the error in my code is.

Input

```
print("(\\                   (\/)") 
print("( '')     (\_/)      (.. )   //)")   
print('O(")(") (\\'.'/)'  '(")(")O (" )')
print('         (")_(")           ()()o')
```

The expected output should be this:

```
(\\               (\/)
( '')    (\_/)   (.. )   //)
O(")(") (\'.'/) (")(")O (" )
        (")_(")        ()()o
```

Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Does not want to run isn't helpful. The traceback show exactly what the problem is. On line 3 you have both single and double quotes that result in SyntaxError. Use tripple quotes on line 3. And on line 1 \\ will result in single \ when printed. Use \\\\ instead, or use raw string.

Comment: Thank you, I found my problem. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
print('''(\\                   (\/)''') 
print('''( '')     (\_/)      (.. )   //)''')   
print('''O(")(") (\\'.'/)'  '(")(")O (" )''')
print('''         (")_(")           ()()o''')
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks, got the solution